# How to save password in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I need to create an IPhone Application...Which will communicate with a website...so it requires username and password...Now I need to know how to save the username and password in iphone...I have already used NSuserdefaults...but that didnt solved my pblm....Also I need to restore the view...from where the user exits the application...So I request you to help me?

Regards and thanks for the support,

Syam

Answer (score 10):

I am a bit paranoid about saving secure data (username/passwords) on plain text files such as plist files or NSUserDefaults.

Apple provides Keychain services to store secure data. It is slightly complicated, view the documentation [Keychain Services Tasks for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1)

They also provide [Generic Keychain app](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the password on a regular file, or you can also store it on a SQLite database.

Comment: This is what I would do, the SQLite database.

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay...

Do u know how to restore the view from where the user exits the application...???

Answer (score 0):

I had a logout functionality in the app I did recently.

I had a hierarchy as :

```
 "BaseUITableViewController
            ^
            |
 "Any subclass of UITAbleView Controller used in project."
```

all of these subclasses had a "Logout" button and the method to call logout service was written in Base class.

as soon as the response for logout request is valid and the session is killed I call following method (which of your interest in contrast to the above text :))

```
-(void)gotoMainScreenOnLogout
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;//to make the previous view invisible 
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;        //27 JUNE UPDATE
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];                    //27 JUNE UPDATE

//  MYAPPViewController *homeViewController = [[MYAPPViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MYAPPViewController" bundle:nil];
MYAPP_LoginUIVIewController *homeViewController =[[MYAPP_LoginUIVIewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYAPP_LoginUIVIewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeViewController ];
[nc.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
//
UIWindow *MYAPP_window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]objectAtIndex:0];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.8;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFade;
transition.delegate = self;
//...
[MYAPP_window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[MYAPP_window removeAllSubviews]; // not needed anymore
[MYAPP_window addSubview:nc.view];
[homeViewController release];
```

}

hope this helps.