# How to save password in UserDefault using the NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone

I want to save password when user select remember me checkbox. I have code like this:is this correct?

In Appdelegate.m

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *savedno;
```

in .m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.navcontrol =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController ];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navcontrol;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.savedno=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"pass"];

    if(savedno==nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *saveDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:savedno forKey:@"pass"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]registerDefaults:saveDict];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */

    NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userdefault setObject:savedno forKey:@"pass"];
}
```

//ViewDelegate.m file

//event of checkbox

```
-(IBAction)check:(id)sender
{
    if (checkboxSelected == 0)
    {
        [checkboxButton setSelected:YES];
        [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        // [userdefault setObject:user.text forKey:@"user"];
        // [userdefault setObject:pass.text forKey:@"pass"];
        self.callno=pass.text;
        pass.text=self.callno;
        AppDelegate *appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        appdelegate.savedno=self.callno;

        NSLog(@"Data saved");    
        checkboxSelected = 1;        
    }
    else
    {
        [checkboxButton setSelected:NO];
        [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];                                 
        user.text=@"";
        pass.text=@"";
        checkboxSelected = 0;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    user.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

    AppDelegate *appdel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if([user.text isEqualToString:@"bhoomi"])
    {
        pass.text=appdel.savedno;
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

    checkboxSelected = 0;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
`
```

Comment: Why don't you save the password in the keychain?

Comment: Keychain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2600619/14955

Comment: Please, please, please use the keychain. Watch WWDC2012 - Session 704 from about 17 minutes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code...

```
NSUserDefault *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefault  setValue:pass_str forKey:@"pass"];

[userDefault  synchronize];
```

may this will help you...

Comment: where you will get your password.. i mean if at viewController you have text field then you have to do on viewController

Comment: just fill your user name in text field and when he will do submit button or login button whatever you want.. get username and password from text field in your button function and save it to NSUsedrDefalut like above ... got my point??

Comment: ok then in your textFieldDidEndEditing: method use the followinf line ... 
NSUserDefault *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *userName =    [userDefault valueForKey:@"UserName"];

if([textFiel.text isEqualToString:userName]){//then set your passowrd}
else{show alert and return; }.. hope got my point

Answer (score 7):

Don't. `NSUserDefaults` isn't the place for confidential information like passwords. Instead, use the [KeyChain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the keychain to store information like passwords.

Have a look at [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security), it will allow to easily use the keychain in your app. It provides two methods: storeUserName:andPassword: and getPasswordForUsername that will make it a snap, and secure!

Answer (score 1):

To save to user defaults do the following

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"YourPassword" forKey:@"passowrd"];
//then call
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To get it back

```
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 1):

after setting value to NSUserDefaults you have to synchronize once to get it saved. Use following statement to do so.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

- It is wise to store credentials into keychain rather than NSUserDefaults.
- [Use this KeyChain Helper class for the same](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security/)

Comment: Why downvote ? and also without specifying reason ? That is something weird.